# Formula for number is decimal or not in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my table I have values as:

```
5
6
12.06
15.933
```

I need to display in [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) as

```
5
6
12.1
15.9
```

Can anyone get me formula to do above?

I tried this formula:

```
tonumber({table.field})
```

But I get the result as below which I don't want.

```
5.0
6.0
12.06
15.93
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also:

1. add the field to your report normally
2. right click it, select "Format Field"
3. Click the `Number` tab and click `Customize`
4. In the `Decimals` formula, enter something like: 
   `if {@test} - truncate({@test}) <> 0 then
   1
   else
   0`

The formula tests if the field is an int.  If so, show 1 decimal place, otherwise show 0.  This method has the advantage of not changing the datatype to text which will make totalling and calculating easier.

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula with:

```
if remainder({database.field},truncate({database.field})) = 0 then
  totext({database.field},0)
else
  totext({database.field},1);
```

This will however convert the number to text so if you have to do any calculations then just use the original {database.field} in your calculations. This will also round to one decimal place. Not the most elegant!

Answer (score 1):

- Choose "format field" on the field you want to edit
- In "Decimals" field out a Formula
- Type this formula

  ```
   if(Int({Field})<>{Field}) 
    then 1 
    else 0
  ```